# Ubuntu lightdm login issue in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, lightdm

We recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit Desktop OS on Dell PC.

After installing certain packages on it, we restarted the PC. We are unable to login in GUI but able to login via console. You may check the [image: attached] image.

Kindly help us in solving this.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the lightdm.conf and restarting the pc?

Comment: Yes, I did that. didn't help

Comment: are you logged into console as `mytxxx06`?

Comment: You said you installed certain packages.  What exactly did you install ?

Comment: Sharad Gautam, I am able to login from console.

Comment: Serg, I installed QT application on it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to login through console check output of

```
ls -l ~/.Xauthority
```

It must be owned by you. If it is owned by root - that's the problem.

```
chown username:username .Xauthority
```

should fix it

Comment: .Xauthority file is owned user itself. its not owned by root. Even I created a new user, the same thing is happening, none of the users are able to login.